# Gulp SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: gulp, npm

Имеется следующий `gulpfile.js`

При попытке запуска выдает следующую ошибку:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at loadInputSourceMapFromLocalUri (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\town\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\apply-source-maps.js:177:15)
at extractInputSourceMapFrom (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\town\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\apply-source-maps.js:116:17)
at fetchAndApplySourceMap (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\town\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\apply-source-maps.js:79:10)
at doApplySourceMaps (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\town\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\apply-source-maps.js:57:14)
at C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\town\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\apply-source-maps.js:86:12
at extractInputSourceMapFrom (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\town\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\apply-source-maps.js:122:14)
at fetchAndApplySourceMap (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\town\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\apply-source-maps.js:79:10)
at doApplySourceMaps (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\town\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\apply-source-maps.js:57:14)
at applySourceMaps (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\town\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\apply-source-maps.js:33:5)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это при том, что я пытаюсь запустить `gulp` именно в этом проекте, с тем же самым `gulpfile` все хорошо в другом проекте, что может быть не так?

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    less = require('gulp-less'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    fileinclude = require('gulp-file-include'),
    pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
    htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin'),
    cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat')



var path = {

    build: {
        html: 'dest',
        less: 'app/css',
        js: 'dest/temp/js',
        img: 'dest/temp/img',
        fonts: 'dest/temp/fonts',
        libs: 'dest/temp/libs',
        css: 'dest/temp/css'
    },

    src: {
        html: 'app/*.html',
        less: 'app/less/styles.less',
        js: 'app/js/*.js',
        img: 'app/img/**/*.*',
        fonts: 'app/fonts/**/*.*',
        libs: 'app/libs/**/*.*',
        css: 'app/css/*.css'
    },

    watch: {
  html: 'app/**/*.html',
  js: 'app/js/*.js',
  less: 'app/less/**/*.less',
  img: 'app/img/**/*.*',
        fonts: 'fonts/**/*.*',
        css: 'app/css/*.css'
 }
}

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "dest",
            index: "product.html"
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('build:html', function() {
    gulp.src([path.src.html, '!app/template/*.html'])
    .pipe(fileinclude({
      prefix: '@@',
      basepath: '@file'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.html))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
})


gulp.task('build:less', function(){
    gulp.src(path.src.less)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.less))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
});

gulp.task('build:css', ['build:less'], function() {
    gulp.src(path.src.css)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(concat('styles.min.css'))
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('/'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
})

gulp.task('build:js', function() {
    gulp.src(path.src.js)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.js))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
})

gulp.task('build:img', function() {
    gulp.src(path.src.img)
    .pipe(imagemin([
        imagemin.svgo({
          plugins: [
            { optimizationLevel: 3 },
            { progessive: true },
            { interlaced: true },
            { removeViewBox: false },
            { removeUselessStrokeAndFill: false },
            { cleanupIDs: false }
         ]
       }),
       imagemin.gifsicle(),
       imagemin.jpegtran(),
       imagemin.optipng()
      ]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.img))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
})

gulp.task('build:fonts', function() {
    gulp.src(path.src.fonts)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.fonts))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
})

gulp.task('build:libs', function() {
    gulp.src(path.src.libs)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.libs))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
})

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(path.watch.html, ['build:html'])
    gulp.watch(path.watch.css, ['build:css'])
    gulp.watch(path.watch.fonts, ['build:fonts'])
    gulp.watch(path.watch.libs, ['build:libs'])
    gulp.watch(path.watch.js, ['build:js'])
    gulp.watch(path.watch.img, ['build:img'])
    gulp.watch(path.watch.less, ['build:css'])
})

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync', 'watch', 'build:html', 'build:img', 'build:css', 'build:js', 'build:libs', 'build:fonts']);
```

Comment: без соурсмапов собирается?

Comment: @ThisMan, эта ошибка пропала сама по себе сейчас, я не знаю почему, ничего не менял в проекте вообще.

Comment: @ThisMan, теперь другая. Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\town\app\css\styles.css'